# Collecting strings without wasteful malloc in C99

Tags: c, malloc

I'm currently reading 21st Century C, and playing around with some contrived example code.

The problem I'm attempting to solve it not repeatedly `malloc()` and `realloc()`ing the buffer, the full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/leehambley/779297780cc428f7d4a7), but I have inlined the important parts below:

The function `_sgr_color(int modes[])` should be called like, both are equivalent, the 2nd is a macro wrapping the compound literal:

```
_sgr_color((int[]){31,45,0}); // literal function 
sgv_color(31, 45);            // va macro wrapper
```

These should both return something like `\x1b[;31;45m`.

However the magic numbers are defined as constants in the original code (`typedef enum SGR_COLOR { SGR_COLOUR_BLACK = 31}`, etc.)

Inside the function `_sgr_color(int modes[])`, I know that I need to allocate a buffer, and return it, no problem, but I don't know how long to make the buffer until I walk the `modes[]`:

I have annotated the code inline:

```
/* Static, to make callers use the macro */
static char *_sgr_color(int modes[]) {
  /* We increment the writeOffset to move the "start" pointer for the memcpy */
  int writeOffset = 0;

  /* Initial length, CSI_START and CSI_END are `\x1b[' and `m' respectively */
  int len = strlen(CSI_START CSI_END);

  /* Loop over modes[] looking for a 0, then break, count the number of entries
   * this is +1 to account for the ; that we inject.
   */
  for (int i = 0; modes[i] > 0; i++) {
    len += sizeof(enum SGR_COLOR) + 1;
  }

  /* Local buffer, unsafe for return but the length at least is right (no +1 for
   * \0
   * because we are in control of reading it, and we'll allocate the +1 for the
   * buffer which we return
   */
  char buffer[len];

  /* Copy CSI_START into our buffer at position 0 */
  memcpy(buffer, CSI_START, strlen(CSI_START));
  /* Increment writeOffset by strlen(CSI_START) */
  writeOffset += strlen(CSI_START);

  /* Loop again over modes[], inefficient to walk it twice,
   * but preferable to extending a buffer in the first loop with
   * realloc().
   */
  for (int i = 0; modes[i] > 0; i++) {

    /* Copy the ; separator into the buffer and increment writeOffset by
     * sizeof(char) */
    memcpy(buffer + writeOffset, ";", sizeof(char));
    writeOffset += sizeof(char);

    /* Write the mode number (int) to the buffer, and increment the writeOffset
     * by the appropriate amount
     */
    char *modeistr;
    if (asprintf(&modeistr, "%d", modes[i]) < 0) {
      return "\0";
    }
    memcpy(buffer + writeOffset, modeistr, sizeof(enum SGR_COLOR));
    writeOffset += strlen(modeistr);
    free(modeistr);
  }

  /* Copy the CSI_END into the buffer, no need to touch writeOffset */
  memcpy(buffer + writeOffset, CSI_END, strlen(CSI_END));
  char *dest = malloc(len + 1);

  /* Copy the buffer into the return buffer, strncopy will fill the +1 with \0
   * as per the documentation:
   *
   * > The stpncpy() and strncpy() functions copy at most n characters
   * > from src into dst.  If src is less than n characters long, the
   * > remainder of dst is filled with `\0' characters.
   * > Otherwise, dst is not terminated.
   *
   */
  strncpy(dest, buffer, len);
  return dest;
}
```

Here the code works, an example program outputs the correct bytes in the correct order, and the colour codes work, however the problems exist as marked:

1. The use of `asprintf()` undermines my reasons for wanting not to repeatedly call `malloc()`.

I'm struggling to see how I can simplify this code, if at all, and how that might compromise my  desire not to repeatedly allocate memory.

Comment: The only way to avoid repeatedly allocating memory is to allocate enough for the whole job up front.  If you can't do that, then it's a matter of how to organize those allocations.

Comment: Can you use your expertise to compose an answer I can accept, perhaps assigning a reasonably sized buffer on the heap, iterating over things and somehow detecting (with `strncpy`?) the end of the string, and mallocing, and copying just to that point? Also how can I convert the integer to a char* without the `asprintf` call?

Comment: Note: `sizeof(enum color)` is not a correct way to estimate the buffer size required.  It gives the size of the internal representation of `enum color`, not the size of a *formatted* representation.

Comment: Thanks you are absolutely right, that line `memcpy(buffer + writeOffset, modeistr, sizeof(enum SGR_COLOR));` should read ` memcpy(buffer + writeOffset, modeistr, strlen(modeistr));`, but I'll probably refactor that out using your suggestion below.

Comment: Why +1 in `char *dest = malloc(len + 1);`, code never copies anything into `dest[len]`?  Suggest adding `dest[len] = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can compute the maximum space required based on the number of modes given and the known bounds on their allowed values (plus the known lengths of the constant strings involved).  In that case, the fewest dynamic memory allocations possible would be achieved by

- performing just one `malloc()` to get a buffer large enough to hold everything, regardless of the actual values of the modes,
- writing directly to that buffer (no `asprintf()`),
- and ultimately returning it (no local staging buffer that needs to be copied out).

If desired, you can track how much data is actually written, and `realloc()` at the end to shrink the buffer to the space actually used (which should be cheap and reliable because you would be *reducing* the allocation).  If memory is plentiful then you can skip the `realloc()` -- the output buffer will occupy more memory than it needs to do, but it will be recovered when the buffer is freed.

That's going to be easier and more reliable, and maybe even faster, than computing up front, per mode how much space will be required in the buffer, which is your other alternative for minimizing dynamic allocations.

For example:

```
/* The maximum number of decimal digits in a valid mode */
#define MODE_MAX_DIGITS 6

static char *_sgr_color(int modes[]) {
  char *buffer;
  char *buf_tail;
  char *temp;

  /* Space required for the start and end sequences, plus a string terminator
   * (-1 instead of +1 because the two sizeofs each include space for one
   * terminator)
   */
  int len = sizeof(CSI_START) + sizeof(CSI_END) - 1;

  /* Increase the required length to provide enough space for all the modes and
   * their semicolon separators.
   */
  for (int i = 0; modes[i] > 0; i++) {
    len += MODE_MAX_DIGITS + 1;
  }

  /* Allocate a buffer big enough to hold the entire result, no matter
   * what the actual mode values are
   */
  buffer = malloc(len);
  buf_tail = buffer;

  /* Copy CSI_START into our buffer at the current position (the beginning),
   * and advance the tail pointer to the next available position
   */
  buf_tail += sprintf(buf_tail, "%s", CSI_START);

  /* Loop again over modes[].  It's more efficient to walk it twice than to
   * repeatedly extend the buffer as would be required to walk it only once.
   */
  for (int i = 0; modes[i] > 0; i++) {
    /* Write the ; separator and mode into the buffer; track the buffer tail */
    buf_tail += sprintf(buf_tail, ";%d", modes[i]);
  }

  /* Copy the CSI_END into the buffer, and update the buffer tail */
  buf_tail += sprintf(buf_tail, "%s", CSI_END);

  /* shrink the buffer to the space actually used (optional) */
  temp = realloc(buffer, 1 + buf_tail - buffer);

  /* realloc() should not fail in this case, but if it does then temp
   * will be NULL and buffer will still be valid.  Else temp PROBABLY
   * is equal to buffer, but that's not guaranteed.
   */
  return temp ? temp : buffer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks John, great comments, something I missed, without using `asprintf`, how can I get both the length of a printed string, and write it to the appropriate position, I suppose I can do `char tmp = sprintf("%d", modes[i])`, and `strlen(tmp)`, and use those buffers and offsets to append to the correct place in the final string (before `realloc()`ing to a smaller size)

Comment: If you use regular `sprintf()` to write directly to the buffer then the number of chars written is returned.  I provided an example implementation which I think is pretty tight.

Comment: Note that the example code performs no error checking, except for of the (optional) `realloc()` at the end.  Probably at least the `malloc()` should be checked, as the example code will crash and burn if the `malloc()` fails.  The several `sprintf()`s are unlikely to fail, but if you want to exercise maximal safety then you'll check their return values, too.

Comment: Of course John, as this library is wholly impractical due to burdening the caller with a pointer to be `free()`d. I'm just coding for as much safety as possible to exercise my rusty C skills.